# Get malware infected sites via Google Webmaster Tools api

Tags: api, google-search-console

we have a website with millions of pages. some pages contain "hotlinked" images. if were are problems with target site we see malware warning in Google Webmaster Tools.

Is it possible to get the full list of malware infected pages via Google Webmaster Tools api?

Comment: The "gwt" you're talking about is probably [tag:google-webmaster-tools]; this is not what the [tag:gwt] tag refers to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to use the safebrowsing api rather than the webmaster one (even though you can receive message notifications through webmasters).

There is a fair usage limit of 10,000 urls per day but you can get it upped for free by contacting them (or create your script to limit to 10,000 and continue in 24hrs time).

https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/

Comment: A have implemented safe browsing few month ago, so i will mark your answer as correct:)